# Advance installer create registry using command line

Tags: powershell-2.0, advanced-installer

I have gone through the following link http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/new-reg.html to create registries using command line

```
$InstallerName = "Installer1.2.10"
$registryParams ="/edit $aippath /NewReg -RegKey HKLM\Software\MYApplication\Database\*"
$SourceDir = "D:\AdvanceInstaller"
$AdvanceInstallerPath = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" |  ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath} | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Advanced Installer"}
$InstallerPath= "$($AdvanceInstallerPath.InstallLocation)bin\x86\AdvancedInstaller.com"
$aippath = "$SourceDir\$($InstallerName).aip"
$ProductName = "MYApplication"

$DeleteReg = "/edit $aippath /DelReg -RegKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyApplication"
$ProductParams = "/edit $aippath /SetProperty ProductName=$ProductName"
$repository = "/edit $aippath /SetAppdir -buildname DefaultBuild -path C:\MyApplication"
$newParameters = "/newproject $aippath -type enterprise"
$buildParams = "/build $aippath" 

Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $newParameters -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $ProductParams -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $repository -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "$InstallerPath"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "$DeleteReg"

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()

$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host $stdout
Write-Host $stderr
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $buildParams -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $registryParams -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
```

But I am unable to see the desired registry created after installation. What I need is as per the following after installing the software

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MySoftware]
>   "Path"="C:\MySoftware"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MySoftware\Database]
>   "connectionstring"="server=.;initial db=master"

Also when installing the `msi` the default registry is getting created as `My Company\Project` which I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of trail and error here is the final code

```
$InstallerName = "Installer1.2.10"
$SourceDir = "D:\AdvanceInstaller"
$AdvanceInstallerPath = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" |  ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath} | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Advanced Installer"}
$InstallerPath= "$($AdvanceInstallerPath.InstallLocation)bin\x86\AdvancedInstaller.com"
$aippath = "$SourceDir\$($InstallerName).aip"
$ProductName = "MyApplication"

$DeleteReg = "/edit $aippath /DelReg -regkey HKUD\Software\[Manufacturer]"
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $DeleteReg -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
$registryParams = "/edit $aippath /NewReg -RegKey HKUD\Software\MyApplication -data ''"
$registryParams1 = "/edit $aippath /NewReg -RegValue HKUD\Software\MyApplication\path -data C:\MyApplication"
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $registryParams -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerPath -ArgumentList $registryParams1 -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -ErrorAction Stop
```